# Scrapy - Scraping data from first page only not from "Next" page in pagination

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

Below scrapy code (taken from one blog post) working fine to scrap data from first page only. I added "Rule" to extract data from second page but still it takes the data from first page only.

Any advise?

**Here is the code:**

```js
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from ..items import TfawItem


class MasseffectSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "massEffect"
    allowed_domains = ["tfaw.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.tfaw.com/Companies/Dark-Horse/Series/?series_name=Adventure-Time',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),
                           restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="small-corners-light"][1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[@class="regularlink"]',)),
             callback='parse', follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="regularlinksmallbold product-profile-link"]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_detail_page)
        pass

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        comic = TfawItem()
        comic['title'] = response.xpath('//td/div[1]/b/span[@class="blackheader"]/text()').extract()
        comic['price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="redheader"]/text()').extract()
        comic['upc'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="xh-highlight"]/text()').extract()
        comic['url'] = response.url
        yield comic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems here with your spider. First you are overriding `parse()` method which is reserved by crawlspider, as per documentation:

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Now the second problem is that your LinkExtractor extracts nothing. Your xpath in particular does nothing here.

I would recomment not to use CrawlSpider at all and just go with base scrapy.Spider like this:

```
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'massEffect'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.tfaw.com/Companies/Dark-Horse/Series/?series_name=Adventure-Time',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse all items
        for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="regularlinksmallbold product-profile-link"]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_detail_page)
        # do next page
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'next page')]/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        comic = dict()
        comic['title'] = response.xpath('//td/div[1]/b/span[@class="blackheader"]/text()').extract()
        comic['price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="redheader"]/text()').extract()
        comic['upc'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="xh-highlight"]/text()').extract()
        comic['url'] = response.url
        yield comic
```